# JMeter Report Dashboard start time issue 1/1/70, 12:00 AM

Tags: websocket, jmeter

I have an issue with a Jmeter scenario where my dashboard report is getting a start time of `Start Time     "1/1/70, 12:00 AM"`

The end time is working fine
`End Time   "12/11/21, 10:04 PM"`

In the same script, If I disable the thread group hitting this issue and run another thread group, the start time is ok.  This leads me to think it's a problem with the timing in this particular thread group rather than a problem with my JM props.

I am attempting to simulate long (1 hour +) websocket sessions with a start/pingpong/end.

- Runtime controller with a sub loop controller running the websocket ping/pong in
  the middle.
- The ping/pong uses a runtime controller where duration = rampup + full load time.
- The pingpong loop controller runs every 60 sec for the duration of the thread rampup + full load.
- The overall threadgroup duration is (rampup x 2) + full load.

As far as I can tell all of this adds up to long running threads doing the needed txns, while keeping open websocket connections, and running as expected.

I set DEBUG for Report logging and nothing unusual is jumping out at me as a cause. (Those relevant logs below)

The only Report related JMeter props that I am customizing at runtime or otherwise are the following:

```
 -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity=$REPORTGRAN\
 -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.report_title=$TESTRUNNAME$STARTTIMEJM\
```

Here are the relevant report props from the JM log:

```
2021-12-11 20:53:56,036 DEBUG o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Report generator properties loading
2021-12-11 20:53:56,041 DEBUG o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Loading properties:
...
2021-12-11 20:53:56,091 DEBUG o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Use 'TG10_<REDACTED>_10T-20211211-2053' value for optional property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title'
2021-12-11 20:53:56,091 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.start_date' not found, using default value 'null' instead.
2021-12-11 20:53:56,091 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.end_date' not found, using default value 'null' instead.
2021-12-11 20:53:56,091 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.date_format' not found, using default value 'null' instead.
2021-12-11 20:53:56,112 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Will use date range start date: null, end date: null
```

At the end of the test run log, everything seems to go off without an obvious error.  The report is fine aside from the Start time being 1970.

```
2021-12-11 22:04:17,129 DEBUG o.a.j.r.d.ReportGenerator: Start report generation
2021-12-11 22:04:17,147 INFO o.a.j.r.p.NormalizerSampleConsumer: Using format, 'ms', to parse timeStamp field
2021-12-11 22:04:17,177 DEBUG o.a.j.r.d.ReportGenerator: Start samples processing
2021-12-11 22:04:18,554 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AggregateConsumer#stopProducing(): beginDate produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:18,554 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AggregateConsumer#stopProducing(): endDate produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:18,557 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.ApdexSummaryConsumer#stopProducing(): apdexSummary produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:18,557 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.RequestsSummaryConsumer#stopProducing(): requestsSummary produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:18,583 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.StatisticsSummaryConsumer#stopProducing(): statisticsSummary produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:18,585 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.Top5ErrorsBySamplerConsumer#stopProducing(): top5ErrorsBySampler produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:18,585 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.ErrorsSummaryConsumer#stopProducing(): errorsSummary produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:18,585 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.HitsPerSecondGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): hitsPerSecond produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:18,802 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.LatencyVSRequestGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): latencyVsRequest produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:18,804 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.SyntheticResponseTimeDistributionGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): syntheticResponseTimeDistribution produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:18,804 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.BytesThroughputGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): bytesThroughputOverTime produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:18,805 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.CodesPerSecondGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): codesPerSecond produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:19,016 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimeVSRequestGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): responseTimeVsRequest produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:19,018 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.FilterConsumer#stopProducing(): startIntervalControlerFilter produced 134253 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:19,018 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.TotalTPSGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): totalTPS produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:19,018 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ActiveThreadsGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): activeThreadsOverTime produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:19,018 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.TimeVSThreadGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): timeVsThreads produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:19,022 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimeDistributionGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): responseTimeDistribution produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:19,022 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.TransactionsPerSecondGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): transactionsPerSecond produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:19,023 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimePercentilesGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): responseTimePercentiles produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:19,028 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimePercentilesOverTimeGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): responseTimePercentilesOverTime produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:19,038 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimeOverTimeGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): responseTimesOverTime produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:19,038 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ConnectTimeOverTimeGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): connectTimeOverTime produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:19,038 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.LatencyOverTimeGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): latenciesOverTime produced 0 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:19,039 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.FilterConsumer#stopProducing(): nameFilter produced 287685 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:19,039 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.FilterConsumer#stopProducing(): dateRangeFilter produced 57537 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:19,039 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.NormalizerSampleConsumer#stopProducing(): normalizer produced 19179 samples
2021-12-11 22:04:19,039 INFO o.a.j.r.p.CsvFileSampleSource: produce(): 19179 samples produced in 1s 862 ms on channel 0
2021-12-11 22:04:19,039 DEBUG o.a.j.r.d.ReportGenerator: End of samples processing
2021-12-11 22:04:19,039 DEBUG o.a.j.r.d.ReportGenerator: Start data exporting
2021-12-11 22:04:19,039 INFO o.a.j.r.d.ReportGenerator: Exporting data using exporter:'json' of className:'org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter'
2021-12-11 22:04:19,198 INFO o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Found data for consumer statisticsSummary in context
2021-12-11 22:04:19,198 INFO o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Creating statistics for overall
2021-12-11 22:04:19,198 DEBUG o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Creating statistics for result data:MapResultData [map={data=ListResultData [items=[ValueResultData [value=Total], ValueResultData [value=19179], ValueResultData [value=306], ValueResultData [value=1.5954950727358048], ValueResultData [value=190.9874341727929], ValueResultData [value=0], ValueResultData [value=18125], ValueResultData [value=2.0], ValueResultData [value=123.0], ValueResultData [value=142.0], ValueResultData [value=4498.600000000002], ValueResultData [value=1.1699789539259888E-5], ValueResultData [value=9.498651393468875E-7], ValueResultData [value=6.08339376620762E-7]]], isController=ValueResultData [value=false]}]
2021-12-11 22:04:19,199 INFO o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Creating statistics for other transactions
2021-12-11 22:04:19,199 DEBUG o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Creating statistics for result data:MapResultData [map={data=ListResultData [items=[ValueResultData [value=[TG10TX3] <REDACTED>], ValueResultData [value=15000], ValueResultData [value=230], ValueResultData [value=1.5333333333333334], ValueResultData [value=1.8258000000000028], ValueResultData [value=0], ValueResultData [value=25], ValueResultData [value=2.0], ValueResultData [value=3.0], ValueResultData [value=3.0], ValueResultData [value=3.0], ValueResultData [value=9.150468903713162E-6], ValueResultData [value=1.7597972097375444E-8], ValueResultData [value=5.2793916292126333E-8]]], isController=ValueResultData [value=false]}]
2021-12-11 22:04:19,200 DEBUG o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Creating statistics for result data:MapResultData [map={data=ListResultData [items=[ValueResultData [value=[TG10TX1] <REDACTED>], ValueResultData [value=514], ValueResultData [value=10], ValueResultData [value=1.9455252918287937], ValueResultData [value=171.44552529182874], ValueResultData [value=64], ValueResultData [value=3856], ValueResultData [value=98.0], ValueResultData [value=115.0], ValueResultData [value=127.0], ValueResultData [value=3220.4500000000044], ValueResultData [value=0.28588241444940937], ValueResultData [value=0.115374967601847], ValueResultData [value=0.015355012494841324]]], isController=ValueResultData [value=false]}]
2021-12-11 22:04:19,200 DEBUG o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Creating statistics for result data:MapResultData [map={data=ListResultData [items=[ValueResultData [value=[TG10TX5] <REDACTED> Transaction], ValueResultData [value=500], ValueResultData [value=0], ValueResultData [value=0.0], ValueResultData [value=139.47400000000002], ValueResultData [value=75], ValueResultData [value=235], ValueResultData [value=142.0], ValueResultData [value=155.0], ValueResultData [value=160.95], ValueResultData [value=172.99], ValueResultData [value=0.2761083957384326], ValueResultData [value=0.11132615017784142], ValueResultData [value=0.05527560656872918]]], isController=ValueResultData [value=false]}]
2021-12-11 22:04:19,200 DEBUG o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Creating statistics for result data:MapResultData [map={data=ListResultData [items=[ValueResultData [value=[TG10TX2] <REDACTED> Transaction], ValueResultData [value=665], ValueResultData [value=20], ValueResultData [value=3.007518796992481], ValueResultData [value=4774.747368421048], ValueResultData [value=65], ValueResultData [value=18125], ValueResultData [value=3917.0], ValueResultData [value=7708.199999999998], ValueResultData [value=10085.599999999995], ValueResultData [value=13883.720000000001], ValueResultData [value=0.36644448558908843], ValueResultData [value=0.15569962294102282], ValueResultData [value=0.049384120128216996]]], isController=ValueResultData [value=false]}]
2021-12-11 22:04:19,200 DEBUG o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Creating statistics for result data:MapResultData [map={data=ListResultData [items=[ValueResultData [value=[TG10TX4] <REDACTED>], ValueResultData [value=2500], ValueResultData [value=46], ValueResultData [value=1.84], ValueResultData [value=120.9975999999999], ValueResultData [value=65], ValueResultData [value=540], ValueResultData [value=120.0], ValueResultData [value=132.0], ValueResultData [value=136.0], ValueResultData [value=147.0], ValueResultData [value=0.7160305785154739], ValueResultData [value=0.23962354889242957], ValueResultData [value=0.19858660576015094]]], isController=ValueResultData [value=false]}]
2021-12-11 22:04:19,200 INFO o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Checking output folder
2021-12-11 22:04:19,200 INFO o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Writing statistics JSON to <REDACTED>/statistics.json
2021-12-11 22:04:19,255 INFO o.a.j.r.d.ReportGenerator: Exporting data using exporter:'html' of className:'org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter'
2021-12-11 22:04:19,257 DEBUG o.a.j.r.d.HtmlTemplateExporter: Start template processing
2021-12-11 22:04:19,258 INFO o.a.j.r.d.HtmlTemplateExporter: Will generate dashboard in folder: <REDACTED>
2021-12-11 22:04:19,434 INFO o.a.j.r.d.HtmlTemplateExporter: Report will be generated in: <REDACTED>, creating folder structure
2021-12-11 22:04:19,436 INFO o.a.j.r.d.TemplateVisitor: Copying folder from '/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/report-template' to '<REDACTED>', got message: <REDACTED>, found non empty folder with following content [<REDACTED>/statistics.json], will be ignored
2021-12-11 22:04:19,831 DEBUG o.a.j.r.d.HtmlTemplateExporter: End of template processing
2021-12-11 22:04:19,831 DEBUG o.a.j.r.d.ReportGenerator: End of data exporting
2021-12-11 22:04:19,831 DEBUG o.a.j.r.d.ReportGenerator: End of report generation
```

Any suggestions on what to dig into next?

Comment: 1/1/70, 12:00 AM is the "year zero".  So look for something that might cause you to make a date/time from zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a bug in JMeter or in the WebSocket Sampler plugin, if you replace the plugin with some other sampler, like [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) or [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide) and the issue will be reproducible - raise an issue in [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

If the issue occurs only with WebSocket Samplers plugin open the issue in the [plugin repository](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/issues?status=new&status=open)

In the meantime you can override the test start date by setting `jmeter.reportgenerator.start_date` just like you override the granularity and the test title.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, legend!  Great suggestions.  

The Dummy sampler worked great in a repro and I see a correct start date in the report.  I was so frustrated with this and this gives me a some piece of mind.

I will break this websocket threadgroup out into an example script and get it ready for repro for bugzilla.  This is the Peter D WebSocket plugin BTW. 

In the meantime, I will get that .start_date into my JM startup wrapper for a workaround.